# Exported frame from Figma to Zeplin doesn't let me download image assets

Tags: figma, zeplin

I designed a screen in Figma, and I exported the screen to Zeplin.
But on Zeplin the screen doesn't have any image assets, only arrow icons were available for download.
I tried to google how to export image assets on Zeplin, but none of the result was really relative.

How to download images that were exported from Figma to Zeplin?

Answer (score 0):

Before transferring your Figma designs to Zeplin, you have to ensure the seamless integration of all images within the Figma file.

If you still encounter a problem where images fail to appear in Zeplin, a straightforward solution would be to perform a new export from Figma.

*Contact the Zeplin support team if you need more help about this.*